# TableView not displaying any data except the empty rows

Tags: ios, tableview

[image]I have following code :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

     NSString *tableId = @"details";  
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableId];  

     if(cell == nil)  
     {  
          cell = [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableId];  
     }

[((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101]) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[homeInvCaptureViewModel.productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

return cell;

}
```

I have a table view in storyboard. Yet, my data is not shown up in my table rows. (i.e., imageview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try your code, and it's working for me, so I see some explanations for your bug:

1. Did you set `101` for your ImageView's tag in your storyboard?
2. Did you set `details` as cell's identifier is  in your storyboard?
3. Are you sure your image's name from your `productArray` exists in your project's images?

You should set an image at your ImageView in your storyboard to identify,

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I was jsut missing the tag!!